# How to fix media volume stuck on zero?

Tags: volume-control

Today I tried to play a video but my media volume was on zero.

I used the volume button on my phone but it did not increase the media volume. I then went to the settings --> sound --> media but I could not change the media volume from zero.

The reason i could not change the media volume was because media volume slider was grayed out... So I could touch or change it in any way.

It's a very unintuitive problem and many others seem to have it if you [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=volume+stuck+on+mute+zero+site%3Aandroid.stackexchange.com&rlz=1Y3TXLS_enUS533US533&oq=volume+stuck+on+mute&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2.14772j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=volume+stuck+on+mute+Android).

Answer (score 9):

Mine wasnt caused by an app.  My Do Not Disturb was accidentally set to do not disturb for anything.  Changing the settings worked.

Comment: My problem with this was also caused by the Do Not Disturb setting.

Comment: Just experienced this issue which still exists in Android 9 Pie. Toggling Do Not Disturb unintuitively disables/enables the settings and button sound effects sliders with no indication whatsoever as to why. I don't understand why DND should prevent me from listening to videos on Twitter either when the main reason to use it is to silence the ringer sound...

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be somehow caused by an app. If you close the right app the media volume slider becomes unstuck.

If you are having trouble finding the right app, look for any app having to do with sound.

If you still can't, find the specific app keep closing apps until the media volume becomes unstuck.

Alternatively you can close all your apps and that should guarantee unlocking the media volume.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted mine the now. It was DPT delivery app that caused it.
Media slider button now working.